# Ontario HST rebate: Does each person in the same home get the HST rebate if they file their own taxes?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

Does each person in the same home get the HST rebate if they file their own taxes?

Answer (score 1):

**Married couples or common-law partners** collect the larger rebate level *together,* not individually, and provided they file a tax return and have income below the family limit.  The person whose tax return is processed by CRA first will receive the rebate in their name.

But, any other **single individuals** in the home *over the age of 18* (yes, that includes adult children still at home) can each collect the smaller rebate level, as single individuals, provided they filed a tax return and have income below the single individual limit.

Refer to the Ministry of Revenue's FAQs:

- [Who is considered to be a single individual?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q19)  Excerpt:

> You are considered to be a single
>   individual, if you are single,
>   separated, divorced, or widowed, and
>   you are 18 years of age or older and
>   do not live with any dependent
>   children under the age of 18. [...]

- [Who qualifies as a family?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q15)  Excerpt:

> Married couples or common-law partners
>   (with or without children) and single
>   parents will qualify as families.